# failed install of cassandra PHP PDO for CentOS

Tags: php, cassandra, centos, cql

I can get cassandra pdo to compile for CentOS 5 PHP 5.5, but it fails all tests.  I have the extension setup in the php.ini and thrift is installed.  There is some documentation for debian and ubuntu on this but not for CentOS.  Any ideas of something I could be missing?  Or a way I could get more info?  phpinfo() does not show the pdo_cassandra module being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge YACassandraPDO not stable.
Please check this PHP library http://evseevnn.github.io/php-cassandra-binary/

It is written by me, and how to work with it is similar to the PDO wrapper. Maybe it will suit you.